# how to make custom plugin of TinyMCE in react js?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

The code of the `TinyMCE` editor in `react js` is

```
import { Editor} from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
 <Editor className="editor"
                            onKeyUp={onclick}
                            apiKey="**********************8"
                            onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
                            initialValue="<p></p>"
                            
                            init={{
                                height: 500,
                                selector: 'textarea local-picer',
                                menubar: true,
                                plugins: [
                                    'textcolor', 'autolink',
                                    'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview', 'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'insertdatetime', 'media', 'emoticons', 'table'
                                ],
                                toolbar: ' casechange blocks bold italic textcolor emoticons alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  bullist numlist checklist  image media | undo redo  ',
                                content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
                                image_title: true,
                                automatic_uploads: true,
                                file_picker_types: 'image',
                                /* and here's our custom image picker*/
                                file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
                                  var input = document.createElement('input');
                                  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                                  input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                                  input.onchange = function () {
                                    var file = this.files[0];
                              
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = function () {
                                      var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                                      var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                                      var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                                      var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                                      blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                                      cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                  };
                              
                                  input.click();
                                },
                                images_file_types: 'jpg,svg,webp',
                                images_dataimg_filter: function(img) {
                                    return !img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
                                  }
                            }}
                        />
```

Every thing is working properly but I find an error of `Line 296:56:  'tinymce' is not defined  no-undef`. This error is occur in `custom plugin` that helps to upload the local files. I read the documentation but I am unable to find the solution because I am not getting any library for `tinymce` variable that is use in custom plugin. The problem is that everything is working properly. even the local images can be selected but the error  Line 296:56:  `'tinymce' is not defined  no-undef` is shown when I load the page. I just stuck on the error that is appear in screen. I am unable to use the `tinymce` variable because I don't know which library it is containing. kindly check the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With react, you cannot use tinymce.activeEditor. Instead you need to initiate the tinymce editor with a ref. First pass the ref to the onInit prop like so

```
const editorRef = useRef(null)
<Editor
onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
...otherProps
/>
```

Then anywhere in your code you have the variable `tinymce` you need to replace that with `edtiorRef.current`.

That'll fix your issue and errors.

Comment: I am trying `editorRef.PluginManager.add(name, pluginFunction)` but getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')`. How do I add a plugin to the instance?

Comment: react doesn't have access to the pluginManager unfortunately.